# Try to iterate through a string and stop at a certain word using R

Tags: r

I am trying to stop the count once we hit the word great, but I can't seem to figure it out. The only `stringr` function I can use is `str_sub` and it must be in a while or repeat loop.

```
library(stringr)
st <- c("Hello, Iowa. Congratulations to the Iowa hawkers. That was a big win today. I’m thrilled to be back. That was a big win. But I am thrilled to be back especially on such great news as that, that was a big one. You’ve been a great school, a great team, a great tradition, really an amazing job and it all started right here and we’re going to keep it here. Number one, right? We’re going to keep it here. The fairgrounds so they broke the record tonight in the history of the fairgrounds. I don’t know how old it is, but in the history of the fairgrounds, this is the most people they’ve had. So thank you very much.")
print(st)

s <- str_sub(st, 1, 5) == "great"
s
i <- 1
while (TRUE) {
  name <- st[i]
  if (name == s) {
    break
  } 
  i <- i + 1
}
```

Comment: The `s` is a logical vector as per your code i.e. `== "great"` and thus `name == s` is not doing anything.  Also, `st[i]` is not subsetting word as you intended because `st` is a string string and the indexing won't work with strings in R or else have to split with `strsplit`

Comment: How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Try `v1 <- strsplit(st, "[[:punct:] ]+")[[1]];v1[seq_len(grep("great", v1)[1])]` or if you need the substring try `stringr::str_remove(st, "(?<=great).*")`

Comment: You could also try `which(strsplit(st, ' ')[[1]] == "great")`

Comment: I can only use str_sub

Comment: @marie then you may use `str_sub(st, 1, str_locate(st, "great")[, 'start']-1)`

Comment: FYI, if you are doing homework and the homework *requires* that you use a specific package and/or function, please be clear about that in your question.

Comment: Okay, I updated it!

Comment: @marie Do you required to return a vector of words or a single substring at the end

Comment: "Use a while or repeat loop and break to find the location of the first “great” in terms of the number of characters. The only string function you can use is str_sub."

Comment: @marie is the expected output `170` or `170-174`?

Comment: I think 170 since we would be looking at grouped characters of 5.

Comment: Something like `i <- 1; while(TRUE) {
   
   v1 <- str_sub(st, i, i + 5);
   print(v1)
   if(trimws(v1) == "great") {
    break
   }
   
   i <- i + 1}`

Comment: I think this works great, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Using for, while or repeat loops is generally not as clean and efficient in coding as is using sapply or lapply and vectorized functions:

```
which( sapply(strsplit(st, " "),"==","great"))
#[1] 34 46 49 52
```

This creates a multi-element list and applies the test "==" with the second argument "great" to all the items in the list. The vectorized `which` function returns the their numeric positions based on the logical vector. At the moment it only uses a blank as a splitting criterion, but you might want to generalize that by making the split argument a more inclusive regex pattern, perhaps `"[ [:punct:]]"`.

```
which( sapply(strsplit(st, "[ [:punct:]]"),"==","great"))
[1] 41 56 60 64
```

Notice that the results change when the split criterion is expanded. You may need to fiddle with it more to get results that you consider correct. The access to the results of strsplit require that you understand that it is a list rather than a straight-forward vactor:

```
strsplit(st, "[ [:punct:]]")[[1]][41]
[1] "great"
```

Comment: `sapply` isn't necessary here, since `strsplit` is already vectorized. `which(strsplit(st, ' ')[[1]] == "great")` gives an identical result.

Comment: Interesting. I remembered strsplit as returning a nested list. Thanks.